# Implementation of IIR filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, poles-zeros

Suppose we have a discrete input waveform (with sampling frequency Fs = 32*56e9). We want to filter this waveform with a filter that has two complex conjugate poles (at 22 GHz) and one zero (at 17GHz) and let's say the gain of the filter is 1.

I'd like someone to provide steps for calculating the filter coefficients.

Comment: I mean, I've *seen* acquisition systems that do > 32 GS/s. I've yet to see a single one that does > 1.5 terasamples a second. Either you're in the business of EM simulation for Terahertz cavities or something, or you're doing something strange. Considering your tones are > 32/2 GHz, I'm considering the latter option... anyway, you're asking for code written to your specification, and we don't do that here. There's nothing special about these signals, just do this like you would implement any other IIR. Nobody would need a matlab toolbox for that, the functions are in base matlab.

Comment: Well, I am looking more for a general approach and solution (but a detailed one) and not necessarily the code i.e., how filter coefficients should be calculated and applied to the signal.

Comment: Ok, then I'll take the freedom to remove the matlab-implementation specific aspect from your question.